# WP_Query Multiple Taxonomies Filter

Tags: wordpress, filtering

I have several taxonomies registered to a custom post type. I am trying to give users the option to filter posts within this custom post type via a combination of terms within these taxonomies.

**Problem**
I'm able to get the results I want if the user selects at least one term for each taxonomy, but if only one term is selected OVERALL (i.e. nothing is selected for other taxonomies), then the result is blank.

**Concrete Example of Problem**
My custom post type is "product". I have created several different taxonomies for this post type  and different terms within each taxonomy, like the following:

Product Types (Taxonomy 1)

- Postcards
- Art Prints
- Greeting Cards

Themes (Taxonomy 2)

- Inspirational
- Sweet
- Funny

Etc.

If the user chooses "Postcards" and "Inspirational," then the query is able to return products that have both "Postcards" and "Inspirational" selected. However, if the user checks "Postcards" only, then the result is blank. What I want is for the query to return all posts with "Postcards" checked.

Here is what I have tried:

First I create the filters by outputting them as checkboxes on the page

```
<form method="GET">
    <h3>Product Types</h3>
    <?php $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'product_types',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ]);
    foreach ($terms as $term) :
    ?>
    <label onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="collections[]"
            value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"
            <?php checked(
            (isset($_GET['collections']) && in_array($term->slug, $_GET['collections']))
            ) ?>
        />
        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
    </label>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <h3>Themes</h3>
    <?php $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'themes',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ]);
    foreach ($terms as $term) :
    ?>
    <label onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="collections[]"
            value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"
            <?php checked(
            (isset($_GET['collections']) && in_array($term->slug, $_GET['collections']))
            ) ?>
        />
        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
    </label>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Then, I use tax_query to look for products that match the user's selections.

```
<?php
    $collections_val = $_GET['collections'];

    $args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ];
    // Append our tax-query if we have terms. Make sure it is a valid string or array
    $terms = $collections_val;
    if ( $terms ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
      [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_types',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $terms,
      ],
      [
        'taxonomy' => 'themes',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $terms,
      ],
    ];
    }
    $product_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $product_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $product_query->have_posts() ): $product_query->the_post(); 
        echo the_title();
    endwhile;
else :
    echo 'No results';
endif; ?>
```

I know this is what my code is telling WP to do b/c I'm using **'relation' => 'AND'**. But for my purposes I need WP to return results even if only one term under one taxonomy is selected.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Did a lot of research already but couldn't find my way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. The key was that I needed to use 'OR' for the relation if the user only ticks checkbox(es) within one taxonomy and 'AND' for all the other scenarios.

Got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54322398/9198856).

If you have more than 2 taxonomies, though, things will get a little more complicated as you have to account for ALL combinations of relationships. You'll also need to query only the taxonomies with ticked checkboxes.

For example, you need assign a different relation value depending on what's been selected:

**Tax 1 + Tax 2**
relation should be ('AND')
only query tax 1 & tax 2

**Tax 1 + Tax 3**
relation should be ('AND')
only query tax 1 & tax 3

**Tax 2 + Tax 3**
relation should be ('AND')
only query tax 2 & tax 3

**Tax 1 + Tax 2 + Tax 3**
relation should be ('AND')
query all 3 taxonomies

**Tax 1 only or Tax 2 only or Tax 3 only**
relation should be ('OR')
query the taxonomy with checked checkboxes only (or just query all 3 since it's an 'OR' relationship. It won't affect the front-end result. It might affect performance if you have a lot of posts, obviously.)

I can post my final code if anyone wants it.